# How to refresh the Log4j2 logger after configuration file is updated

Tags: apache, logging, log4j2

In Log4j2, I am using an xml property file to store configurations. What is the code to refresh the logger to have the new confgurations after I update the configuration file.

I am using the below code to initialize the logger

```
LoggerContext loggerContext=null;
ConfigurationSource source=null;

        try {
            source = new ConfigurationSource(new FileInputStream("./config/log4j2.xml"));
            loggerContext = Configurator.initialize(null, source);
            testFileLogger = loggerContext.getLogger("rollingFileLogger");
 }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

Can you clarify what you are looking for. Having below in the log4j2.xml will refresh the settings after the specified interval:
`<Configuration status="INFO" monitorInterval="30">`

Comment: I am looking for some Java method from the log4j2 API to reload the configuration after I have changed the configuration in the log4j2.xml

Comment: I tried setting the monitorInterval property also, but it does not work. I am on log4j-core-2.8.2 jar.

Comment: hmm..have you tried the reconfigure method on the LoggerContext? still not sure why it does not auto update though ..

Comment: The auto update using monitorInterval is working only when I set the system level property "log4j.configurationFile" and point it to my log4j2.xml file, but, I cannot do this due to some restrictions.

I tried invoking the method loggerContext.reconfigure(); and still no luck.